# unable to share url with image in google+ in ios app

Tags: ios, google-plus

I am working on an app in which I am trying to share an image with a url via google+. I am using GPPNativeShareBuilder for the same. But its not sharing anything and giving following warning "You cannot attach a link and media to a post at the same time."

Same is mentioned in method description on google forum as

- (id) attachImage: (UIImage *) imageAttachment
  If there is an existing media attachment, it is replaced. If imageAttachment is nil, this method does nothing and returns nil. This method cannot be called in combination with either setURLToShare: or setTitle:description:thumbnailURL:.

Please suggest me any solution to resolve this problem.

Comment: Have you got solution for this? I am having same issue. Please suggest. +1

Comment: @Dilip, not yet, actually I did not try more as we changed the requirement.

Comment: I have done research on this and as i found out that we can not add link and image at same time but we can add meta in the site link and add image in that link's meta, Than it will display.

Answer (score 1):

We can not allowed to add image and link same time in the post,
But we can add "meta" in link, Have to add "meta" in the header of the Link page,
And define image in this "meta".

Google use Open Graph (og) meta as Facebook, Here is the sample meta,

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Your Site Name" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of the Post" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description for the post" />
<meta property="og:url" content="URL where you want to redirect on web" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Your image URL" />
```

Here is the Some Sample site that is good example
http://moz.com/blog/meta-data-templates-123
http://www.bruceclay.com/blog/how-to-use-social-meta-tags/

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try this stuff when have some time or have any such requirement in app :)